# Links of menu don't work on localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, joomla

I just copied whole site with XCloner (extention for joomla) and flushed it into my localhost enveronment.
The main page and all administration interface are working and things seems be same between production and localhost enveronments, but just I click on some menu item I receive error 404...

For example:

`http://site.fr/plateaux-repas-paris - give the page

http://localhost.com/site/plateaux-repas-paris - give 404 error

http://localhost.com/site - give main page

http://localhost.com/site/administrator - give administrator login page`


I don't know where start to dig...
Some ideas?
I guess it related to Apache configuration, because joomla instalation just mirrored from the site.

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: localhost.com was need for escape error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you have Joomla's SEF/SEO settings turned on and your local copy doesn't include the `.htaccess` file (they're often missed by the free backup utils).

Just copy your `htaccess.txt` file to `.htaccess` and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I checked .htaccess file, enabled mod_rewrite in httpd.conf and restarted web service. SEF settings: Friendly URLs - Yes, Use mod_rewrite - Yes, Add suffix - No. I have no errors in error.log of Apache2. Interesting that in one trial it worked and changed url to index.php?compoment=.... and opened the page but other cases it not worked. From my expirience, mod_rewrite on Windows is VERY non deterministic and working only SOME-TIMES. So I suspecting that the problem is in mod_rewrite. It is why it working on server (Linux) and not on Windows.

Comment: And! I forget put AllowOverride All. Now it completely works!!!